# Locking the orientation in an iPad app (plist or UIViewController?)

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I'd like the app to work like it would be as if I locked the orientation manually.  I'm trying to find how I can lock the orientation for an app.  In the info.plist, I have this setting:

```
Supported interface orientations (iPad)
Item 0 Landscape (right home button)
Item 1 Landscape (left home button)
```

I thought that would be enough to keep my viewControllers from staying in landscape mode and not portrait.  But it does not.  Do I need to do

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

in ALL my viewControllers?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All though implementing `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in all your view controllers will work, it is probably not the fastest or most practical way of doing what you are trying to accomplish.

If any of your view controllers in your hierarchy do not conform to the orientation change, then iOS will stop trying to rotate them. What this means is that only your root view controller needs to have implemented `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` with only landscape orientations. Each view controller pushed or added will conform to that function.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do this in several of my apps and it was required for several reasons.

In the end and after a lot of testing, we determined that the condition has to be set on the info.plist AND on every viewController.

So make sure it is set on the plist and that every `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`only returns yes for the allowed orientation.

This is because the plist will help you with allowed LAUNCH orientations, but your app could still rotate afterwards, specially when using modal views.

You can download one of my free apps that does thins on iPad: http://itunes.apple.com/mx/app/hoteles-city/id471505865?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do.

I have a different solution however. In every UIViewController, I use:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
    } else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```